Как взять черточку или "\" за строку в питоне
import os, sys
import getpass

file_from = f"C:\Users\{getpass.getuser()}\AppData\Local\Google"  #ругается на первый "\"
file_to = os.rename(file_from, file_to)


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Используйте "raw-string" (добавьте r перед строкой):
file_from = fr"C:\Users\{getpass.getuser()}\AppData\Local\Google"
             ^
          вот тут


да, нашел решение, спасибо вам
